# How to mount HFS+ drive and ignore permissions

Tags: macos, ubuntu, permissions, mount, hfs+

I installed Ubuntu and Windows on my MacBook and Ubuntu is my primary OS; however, all of my media stays on my OSX partition. I want to be able to access it (at least my OSX user's home folder) from Ubuntu without having to launch a media player (or anything else) as root. Also, because I occasionally want to fire up my machine in OSX, I don't want to change anything that I would need to change back frequently (I read a lot about changing UID--I don't exactly understand what this entails, but I wouldn't want to have to change my UID back and forth depending on which OS I'm using).

Also, I saw something about a "noowner" option, but that doesn't seem to do what I want it to.

So I guess I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o noowner /dev/sda2/ /media/Mac
```

And then be able to access all of my media (at least everything in my OSX user's Home folder) without dropping in as root. (for clarity: the above command line entry doesn't do what I want it to do, but I want to be able to do something similar).

Or would it be better to change my UID? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to ignore the permissions, but I ended up changing the UID on my Ubuntu account to match my OSX account:

```
sudo useradd -d /home/tempuser -m -s /bin/bash -G admin tempuser
sudo passwd tempuser
```

Enter new password. Log out, log in as "other" with username "tempuser" and the password you chose earlier. Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo usermod --uid 501 yourusername
sudo chown -R 501:yourusername /home/yourusername
```

*change "yourusername" to your non-temporary user name and 501 to the UID of your Mac account (first Mac account starts at 501, but subsequent users will have different UIDs).

Log out of tempuser and log back into your normal account (this is important; don't just switch users--bad things happen). Open a terminal window and type:

```
sudo userdel -r tempuser
```

For more details, visit [this page](http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems).